# issue with rails, form and relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've a couple of model I've made using the scaffold generator.

There are:

```
rails g scaffold event title:string content:text
rails g scaffold link title:string
```

I would like that each event has many links, and link belongs to events.

So in the event models I've coded:

```
has_many :links
```

And inside the link model:

```
belongs_to :event
```

Moving on I've run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

In order build the database. And I've made a couple of events using scaffold feature.

Now I'd like to add links directly inside the event's show>views.

Inside the show.html.erb (inside the view>events dir) I've written:

```
<%= form_for([@event, @event.links.build]) do |f| %>

<p><%= f.text_field %></p>
<p><%= f.submit "Add the link" %></p>
<% end %>
```

But when I try to visit the show page the browser says:

```
unknown attribute: event_id
```

And it says the error is on this line:

```
<%= form_for([@event, @event.links.build]) do |f| %>
```

What I did wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create the foreign key in your migrations, the `event_id`, by changing the existing ones or creating a new one.

Since you have already migrate them it's recommended you create a new one, so it should be something like this

```
class AddEventForeignKeyToLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_table :links do |t|
      t.references :event
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :links, :event_id
  end
end
```

Edit: Don't forget that to create the migration file you should use the command

```
rails generate migration AddEventForeignKeyToLinks
```

Or any other name then AddEventForeignKeyToLinks

---

routes

```
resources :events do 
  resources :links 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer :) 

But now it says:

    undefined method `event_links_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd1de908320>:0x007fd1de8573e0>

Comment: My routes look like:   resources :links

  resources :events

  resources :peppers

Comment: you might want to define it like `resources :events do
  resources :links
end`. (Will add it to my answer for proper format). This should be fine if links should be assessable only trough an event. If this is not the case I'm not sure but I think you must think better on routes :p like making a route like `match 'events/:id/link/new'`